# How to lock the internal zoom in Age of Empries 1 Definitive Edition?

Tags: gaming

On Dell Latitude 5580 with Windows 10 HOME SP3 with Intel Core I7 7820HQ and Nvidia Geforce 940MX, I run Age of Empires 1 Definitive Edition with default graphics which includes **Zoom level 2**.

Zoom level 1 and Zoom level 4 work very slow and laggy (zoom level 3 doesn't exist).

In Zoom level 2 I have "internal zoom" which changes each time I move the mouse's cursor. I want to lock that zoom to its default level, to save as much Frame Per Second as I can (because if I go too far the FPS goes down, most likely automatically).

How to lock the internal zoom in Age of Empries 1 Definitive Edition?

Comment: Video games are off-topic, sorry. Maybe try on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay, I cannot delete this because I don't have an account so please someone here help me in migrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read at Hotkey Editor under Options and found:

Reset zoom: CTRL+ALT+0
Toggle zoom lock: CTRL+Z

I understand it solves my problem.